# Swift SpriteKit: Creating a realistic driving experience 2D

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

How would I go by creating a realistic driving experience?

I'm using iOS Swift 3 with SpriteKit using the functions applyForce to accelerate when I click the gas button and when braking I add friction to the physicsBody, also I can't seem to turn right, no idea on how to do it.

Right now for turning I'm splitting the screen using the left and right to turn but I'm using applyForce but its very bad because it turns when the car is stopped and in a very unrealistic way.

When I apply force its only to go up so if I do create a turning mechanism and I do a uturn the car will still go up.

Also side note: Multitouch doesn't work?

Any help? Thanks

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    // Multi Touch
    self.view?.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true

    car.carNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    car.carNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: car.carNode.size)
    car.carNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    car.carNode.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0.1
    car.carNode.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.1
    car.carNode.physicsBody?.friction = 0.1
    car.carNode.physicsBody?.mass = 1

    self.addChild(car.carNode)

    // HUD Display
    gas.gasButton.position = CGPoint(x: 300, y: -500)
    self.addChild(gas.gasButton)

    brake.brakeButton.position = CGPoint(x: 150, y: -500)
    self.addChild(brake.brakeButton)

}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

if touching {

    car.carNode.physicsBody?.applyForce(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 180))
  }
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

for touch in touches {
    let location = touch.location(in: self)

    if location.x < self.frame.size.width / 2 {

        // Left side of the screen
        car.carNode.physicsBody?.applyForce(CGVector(dx: -100, dy: 0))

    } else {

        // Right side of the screen
        car.carNode.physicsBody?.applyForce(CGVector(dx: 100, dy: 0))
    }

    // Gas Button
    if (gas.gasButton.contains(location)) {

        touching = true
    }
        // Brake Button
    else if (brake.brakeButton.contains(location)) {

        car.carNode.physicsBody?.friction = 1
    }

  }
}
```

[image: game]

Comment: You may want to take this to https://physics.stackexchange.com/ and find out the principles behind this, then apply that to your code.

Comment: Thanks didn't know they had that

Comment: put pic of your achieved

Comment: @SimonePistecchia i don't have anything archived, am I supposed too?

Comment: achieved not archived. Some pic or gif of your "unrealistic" physics

Comment: @SimonePistecchia i posted a picture but you can't really see whats happening, basically if I go left/right its just a applyForce to the left or when I click gas applyForce on +y. So its not moving smoothly depending on the cars force. In real life you can't turn unless the car is moving. I just dont want to move it on a screens point, want a physics touch to it

Comment: Ok, the pic help to undertund your 2D game. Try  `let velY = car.carNode.physicsBody?.velocity.dy car.carNode.physicsBody?.applyForce(CGVector(dx: 100 * velY, dy: 0))`

Comment: Sorry I will be home in 2 hours from school, what does this code do?

Comment: Calculate your y velocity, if your car Y velocity is zero, your car don't turn, obviously greater is the velocity, greater will be the turn force. You can build a func to limit this force to a maximum value. After this check, is better to use applyAngularImpulse on the front of the car instead applyForce to turn your car

Comment: So the code you gave me goes in the gas button right? And applyAngularImpulse would be the actual turning effect?

Comment: No, override my code only to right side to seee if it works

Comment: yeah it works its just pretty strong but this is the right direction I think, would it be better to use force instead of impulse or no? Also like you said setting up a max speed and a limit

Comment: This is a really intriguing physics engine utilisation design problem. Can anyone think of a forum where we can exchange ideas on the different ways to create "solutions" and their various compromises and benefits?

Comment: @SimonePistecchia how would I go by setting the limit on the force to a max?

Comment: @BroSimple here's one way to think about solving the problems... http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/top-down-car

Comment: @Confused thats really interesting, thats natural objective c? But I'm guessing you learn what they do and apply it your own way?

Comment: @Confused box2d c++ **

Comment: @BroSimple, yes, it's only one way to conceive of using a physics system for 2D, top-down racing. I've a bunch of sketches of other ways to do it, and know that the creator of Chipmunk2D has also spent some time considering this problem in various ways.

Comment: @BroSimple each technique has different benefits/negatives and compromises in features. I've been thinking about it from the perspective of the simplest possible control input and with drift... but haven't come up with anything I like for touchscreens in terms of input systems. So sort of shelved thinking about it. If Tim Cook put a decent GPU/CPU combo in the Apple TV, I might have thought about it more. He had the A9X available at the time he shipped it with the A8, and forced everyone to code games for the Siri Remote, which was stupid does as stupid is. And killed it as a gaming platform.

Comment: Wow yeah I heard something about that and Box2D c++ they work with Swift? Or Chipmunk2D?

Answer (score 0):

**Integration of the comment**

```
for touch in touches {
    let location = touch.location(in: self)

    let velY = car.carNode.physicsBody?.velocity.dy
    let factor:CGFloat = 100
    let maxFactor:CGFloat = 300
    //limit
    let dxCalc = factor * velY > maxFactor ? maxFactor : factor * velY

    if location.x < self.frame.size.width / 2 {

        // Left side of the screen
       car.carNode.physicsBody?.applyForce(CGVector(dx: -dxCalc, dy: 0))

     } else {

        // Right side of the screen
        car.carNode.physicsBody?.applyForce(CGVector(dx: dxCalc, dy: 0))
    }

    // Gas Button
    //etc
```

}
}

Comment: Thank you! and I got an error saying `Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'CGFloat'?`

Comment: Ok, you absolutely need to read SWIFT book before continue! Simple change int to CGFloat, I'll update....

Comment: Yeah sorry I just started learning Swift by doing random projects not the book but I will start reading and also when you said to `applyAngularImpulse` so the car turning looks real, I just do the same thing like you did here with this code? Because the `AngularImpulse` goes crazy

Comment: before apply angularImpulse you must change anchor point of car, and try to put gust a bit of impulse, like factor = 1 or 10